# Can't input non-latin characters into skype on OpenSUSE 13.1

Tags: opensuse, unicode, skype, qt4

I'm currently having an annoying issue with the latest version of Skype 4.3.0.37 (installed from the RPM on a 64bit machine following the official [documentation](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Skype#Installing_Skype)). For some unknown to me reason, I'm unable to input any character other than English ones (i.e. cyrillic characters would appear something similar to "ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð° Ðµ ÑÐµÑÑ").

When I start Skype from a console I get the following output:

```
QIconvCodec::convertFromUnicode: using Latin-1 for conversion, iconv_open failed
QIconvCodec::convertToUnicode: using Latin-1 for conversion, iconv_open failed
```

I can write in cyrillic on every other program but not in Skype. I've checked `/usr/share/fonts` and I have fonts installed there so I'm not quite sure what seems to be the problem here. Any ideas on what's missing?

OS: OpenSUSE 13.1x64_84
Skype: 4.3.0.37
Qt: 4 64 & 32 bit versions

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody has the same issue - you might want to checkout if you've got `glibc-locale-32bit` and `perl-Text-Iconv` installed on your machine. The issue has nothing to do with `qt` as some people have suggested on other topics on the net.